# Providing context for JQuery ID selector helps?

Tags: jquery

For performance, which is faster?

```
$('#' + strControlId);
```

or

```
$('#' + strControlId, $('#' + strContextId));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the first one will be faster.  You will only be calling getElementById once.

One thing to note is the context parameter expects an HTML node and not a jQuery object.  In your case, the second item is still searching in the Document rather than inside

```
$('#' + strContextId)
```

Make sure to add [0] onto the end of the jQuery object in order to pass the HTML node.

To test this, you can use the context property to check which context the selector is selecting from.  For your examples above you can do this

```
console.log($('#' + strControlId).context);
console.log($('#' + strControlId, $('#' + strContextId)).context);
```

And you will find that they both return "Document" context.  If you run

```
    console.log($('#' + strControlId, $('#' + strContextId)[0]).context);
```

It should return whatever element $('#' + strContextId) is pointing too.

Comment: jQuery takes another jQuery or pure DOM element as a context, actually.

Comment: So are you saying 

console.log($('#' + strControlId).context);
console.log($('#' + strControlId, $('#' + strContextId)).context);

will return the same thing? Open up firebug and run these commands on this page

console.log($('#header').context);
console.log($('#header', $('.container')).context);

You will find that they both return Document as the context.  Does that not show that jQuery objects are not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one would be faster (it's doing less).  Though when I think of using the context parameter, I think of doing things like accessing fields in a parent document from an `iframe` or something like:

```
var el = $('#' + strControlId, parent.document);
```

You could try a few benchmarks if you're really curious.

Comment: I dont have access to the jquery environment to run a test, but I will when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an ID as your query I doubt it is any faster.

A good example would be this.

```
var inputs = $('input');
$('[class=this][name=that]', inputs).css('color', 'red');
```